# website Publishing

Tags: asp.net, publishing

I've developed a web application and when i try to publish it in to a folder in my local disk using the PUBLISH option in ASP.NET a error messages is showed at the bottom bar of visual studio "Published Failed" but i couldn't find the error and it doest not provide any error message other than "Published Failed". So is there a way to find the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in the output window - View -> Output it will probably give you a detailed error message.

Answer (score 2):

You should find the error in the Output window (View->Output) - make sure that "View output from [Build]" is selected.